# .png images make my app size very large

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, size, png

I have a lot of .png images of 5-4-3 mb each, and they made a total of around 50-60mb

Has someone got a way to compress .png images to make my app smaller? I was using "**PNGenius**" but it doesn't make a lot of difference.

Comment: what is the resolution of the pngs? you probably don't need them to be more than 72

Comment: The are from 5mb to 1 mb, they are .png for iphone, ipad, ipad retina etc...

Comment: file size isn't what he means. how many pixels wide? like 500x600 pixels, etc

Comment: Well, I just explain you that I use them for iphone, ipad and iphone 5, so the most of the image have that resolution. The most heaviest ones are from ipad retina.

Comment: Unless they have large areas of solid color or alpha transparency, there's no reason to use PNG. Why aren't you just using JPEG?

Comment: @Shmiddty cause they have transparency.

Comment: @Vergmort Alpha transparency or just fully transparent areas?

Comment: @Shmiddty Alpha I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert them to / export them as .PVR.CCZ images. [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.de) is a tool that can help you with that. You'll find more pointers in [this article](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have large `png` images with big dimensions which are resized (the dimensions) in your app. This is why they have big sizes on the disk.

If you resize the dimensions (width and height) first, and **then** you add them in your app the problem is solved.

It looks like this:

```
Situation 1. 
Big image file (very big dimensions) <---> Big size on disk (e.g. 5MB)
    ---> You use it in your app. You resize it in your app. <---> Same size on disk.

Situation 2.
Big image file (very big dimensions) <---> Big size on disk
    ---> You resize it on your disk, and you don't resize it in your app.
         ---> Less size
```

You can resize images very quickly and easy using [IfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). It's a great app that have nice shortcuts.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I made sprites using texture packer and the dimensions (for example) of the ipad retina are this: 4096x2048 and I don't think that I use all that space. So you say this ifan will help me to make mi png fit and low the app size? Will this modify my app funtionality?

Comment: What dimensions has this image INSIDE of you app?

Comment: the size of the resolution of the following devices: Iphone, iphone 5, ipad, ipad 3 (retina, no retina)